# Calculation of MSD with non uniform time intervals

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a matrix that has 2 columns with x and y coordinates. I want to calculate the mean square displacement - which is the squared distance moved from the starting point to another point during a given time, averaged over many different time points - assuming that all the time intervals are equal.

So the working formula is:

`MSD=average(r(t)-r(0))^2 where r(t) is position at time t and r(0) is position at time 0.`

So the code which I am using to calculate this is:

```
#Create a vector to save the square of the distance between successive
#locations
distsq<- numeric(length=nrow(mat))

#Calculate and assign these values
for (i in 2:nrow(mat))
{
distsq[i]<-((mat[i,1]-mat[i-1,1])^2)+((mat[i,2]-mat[i-1,2])^2)
}

#Calculate the mean sq distance for this value of n
MSD[k]<- mean(distsq)
```

Here `mat` is the matrix of x and y values.

So this formula works when the time between 2 successive points is taken to be constant. But suppose that the time between every 2 coordinates is different, then how can I incorporate that component to calculate MSD?

Comment: Proper handling of irregular observation may depend on the specific application.

Comment: Be aware, you can use more than just the "point-point_before" information. Take a look at http://web.mit.edu/savin/Public/.Tutorial_v1.2/Concepts.html#A1

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly efficient (although Roland is only partly correct in his general claim of looping inefficiency.)

```
A <- matrix(1:20, ncol=2)
mean( (A[,1] - A[1,1])^2 + (A[,2] - A[1,2])^2 )
[1] 57
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, loops are very slow in R. So, for performance reasons I would avoid it and make use off `diff()`.

However, your actual question is a mathematical one, which is hard to answer without more background knowledge. You could use some kind of weighting function: a^(abs(deltat-b)), where deltat is the time difference between the two points.

Comment: `diff(a)` would not equal `a[-1]-a[1]` and the second is the series that would be implied by r(t)-r(0).

Comment: The given code example does not do what is outlined in the preceding text. I would replicate the output of the example code with diff().

Comment: True enough, but when responding to someone that is having coding difficulty, I generally go with the description rather than their code.

Comment: Your are probably right. I shouldn't expect that the result of the code was checked with a minimal dataset against the value obtained by manual calculations. But I strongly encourage Maddy to do something like this.